# Search for matches in an array of objects. JS

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I have the following response from the server. I need to search this answer and compare it in turn with each field.

Example:

My task is that I know for sure that there should be 3 objects and each object has its own value for the type field, this is 'API', 'DEFAULT' or 'X'. How can you make it so that you can search for these three values ​​in the whole object and get an error if one of them is missing?

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "54270522",
      "key": "1-16UUC93PT",
      "type": "API"
    },
    {
      "id": "54270522",
      "key": "3-1JOPPEIZI",
      "type": "DEFAULT"
    },
    {
      "id": "54270522",
      "key": "3-1JOPPEIZI",
      "type": "Х"
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can first verify that the length is 3 and then loop over all the types and check if each one is present.

```js
const data = {
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "54270522",
      "key": "1-16UUC93PT",
      "type": "API"
    },
    {
      "id": "54270522",
      "key": "3-1JOPPEIZI",
      "type": "DEFAULT"
    },
    {
      "id": "54270522",
      "key": "3-1JOPPEIZI",
      "type": "Х"
    }
  ],
  "success": true
};
const requiredTypes = ['API', 'DEFAULT', 'Х'];
const types = new Set(data.result.map(({type})=>type));
const good = data.result.length === 3 && requiredTypes.every(type=>types.has(type));
console.log(good);
```

Comment: In case the length is not three or you have the same type twice this will not work

Comment: @MichaelGoldenberg I've fixed the second issue you mentioned, but the question specifies that there should be exactly 3.

Comment: This answer is not correct. In case you have multiple times the same type, for example 'API', 'DEFAULT' and 'API' it will still return true. Even though not all types had been present.

Comment: Lol, nvm. Looks like I can't copy and paste into a console. Keep on doing what you're doing :thumpsup:

Comment: @ROMANSKRIPNIKOV No problem.

Comment: @ROMANSKRIPNIKOV Would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to also know which value of those 3 are missing:

```js
const check = (obj) => {
  if (obj.result.length !== 3) return false;

  let validTypes = ['API', 'DEFAULT', 'X'];

  obj.result.forEach((r) => {
    const index = validTypes.indexOf(r.type);

    if (index !== -1) validTypes.splice(index, 1);
  })

  if (validTypes.length) return `${validTypes.join(', ')} is missing`;

  return true;
};
```

So if you would have something like:

```
const test = {
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "54270522",
      "key": "1-16UUC93PT",
      "type": "API"
    },
    {
      "id": "54270522",
      "key": "3-1JOPPEIZI",
      "type": "DEFAULT"
    },
    {
      "id": "54270522",
      "key": "3-1JOPPEIZI",
      "type": "X2"
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

and you call `check(test)` it will return "X is missing". If all three types are present in the object that gets passed into the check function, it will return true. Of course this can be adjusted as you need. More objects, different types etc...

Comment: Thank ! This is what I need!

Comment: @ROMANSKRIPNIKOV if this is exactly what you need, please also accept the answer as the official answer